# Is it possible to define in which folder my html form posts requests by using a select element?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

Is it possible to define in which folder my HTML form posts requests by using a select element?

For example

```
<select class="dropdown" name="choose_folder">
    <option selected value="post_in_the_folder_webdesign">Request Webdesign</option>
    <option value="post_in_the_folder_private">Request private</option>
    <option value="post_in_the_folder_anything">Anything else</option>
    <option value="post_in_the_folder_spam">Spam</option>
</select>

FORM                                        EMAIL ACCOUNT
 -SELECT                                   -ROUNDCUBE
  -OPTION1=FoLDER1 -> IF THIS OPTION IS CHOSEN, THE EMAIL WILL APPEAR IN -> -FOLDER1
  -OPTION2=FoLDER2 -> IF THIS OPTION IS CHOSEN, THE EMAIL WILL APPEAR IN -> -FOLDER2
  -OPTION3=FoLDER3 -> IF THIS OPTION IS CHOSEN, THE EMAIL WILL APPEAR IN -> -FOLDER3
  -OPTION4=FoLDER4 -> IF THIS OPTION IS CHOSEN, THE EMAIL WILL APPEAR IN -> -FOLDER4
```

Comment: Sorting incoming mails into folders is something you'll need to configure inside your own mail client. I'm guessing you're receiving the form data in a PHP script which sends a mail using something like [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). You'll probably want to add something to that code which adds something to the mail's subject so you can easily set up a rule to sort them into your folders. Could you add the PHP code that processes this form to your question?

Comment: Ok this was my mistake. Im currently chatting with my webspace host to get the permission to use rules in the email client. Can I ask you one more question? What would you add to the sent email (for the rule in the email client)? Editing the subject looks kinda messy in the inbox.

Comment: I'm not sure, simply adding something to the end of the subject doesn't sound too bad to me. I guess you could also add it to the end of the actual message body and have the rule check for that. Either way you'll have to edit *something* in the e-mail and you *will* notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing two things: form processing and email processing.

Form processing is the PHP code to process the form and do something after it has been sumitted. From what you are saying it seems like you are trying to send yourself an email.

Email processing is something your email provider (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.) will do once you receive an email. Depending on the rules you have setup (if rules are available with your email provider) incoming email will be processed one way or another.

Here is what I recommend you do: for each option selected, when processing the form on the server side, simply change or add something to the subject line of the email you are sending. Then in your email account set up an email processing rule to move the email in a different folder depending on the subject line.

**Edit** after first comment:

You could use a custom header starting with X-, which is just an extended mail header (I can't find the appropriate RFC but I remember it's in there). Here is an example of how you could send email:

```
$folder_to_use = 'blabla'; // Read this from the form, make sure it's a string

// Build custom header, don't forget the From: part
// Each header must be separated by a \r\n
$headers = "
    From: webmaster@yoursite.com\r\n
    Reply-To: webmaster@yoursite.com\r\n
    X-folder: $folder_to_use
";

// Send mail
mail ($address_to, 'Subject', $message_text, $headers);
```

Comment: Ok this was my mistake. Im currently chatting with my webspace host to get the permission to use rules in the email client. Can I ask you one more question? What would you add to the sent email (for the rule in the email client)? Editing the subject looks kinda messy in the inbox.

Comment: You could add a custom email header. See my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

You can change the the form's `action` during the `submit` event.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var action = $('form select[name="choose_folder"]').val();
    $('form').attr('action', action);
}
```

Comment: Im a php and jquery beginner. Can you give me an example? :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I see with your code Im able to get the selected option. How to make the form post in the subfolder in my email account?

Comment: That is what the second line does, you change the action of the form

Comment: In my email account Ive created new folder: Webdesign Requests | Private Requests | Anything Else... depending on wich option the client have selected, the form should send it to the according folder. How am I gonna do this? :-S

Comment: I am a little confused.  What do you mean "send it to the folder"?  Filtering emails in your email account would be setup there not on your page.  Please update your question with more detail with what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok this was my mistake. Im currently chatting with my webspace host to get the permission to use rules in the email client. Can I ask you one more question? What would you add to the sent email (for the rule in the email client)? Editing the subject looks kinda messy in the inbox.